# How to make combined taskbar buttons more distinct in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar

I am adjusting the Windows 7 taskbar and am reasonably happy with it. I have Taskbar `Taskbar Buttons` setting at `Always combine, hide labels` which is doing what I want and what it says. What I would like to change is indication on the Taskbar that Windows has combined several windows to make it stand out more. Any ideas on how to make this happen (e.g., make a combined icon a different color, make the edges stand out more)?

Comment: As I've used Win7 more I've come to realize that the behavior I missed from WinXP was the ability to see how many windows for each application I had open. The "Never Combine" setting achieves this and so far I have few enough windows open that I usually don't run out of room on my taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a personal preference, but I've found the Pink to stand out the best.  The buttons are bordered black under that color and the glass layer on top contrasts well enough.

The other option is to select "Combine only when full. . ."

Comment: meaning the choosing the color pink for the window color or is this a theme?

Comment: Pink as in for the window. I probably should of made sure you aren't using the classic theme.